# How to create single public and private route table from vpc terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

Iam using the terraform vpc module to create vpc, my vpc has no igw and nat gateway. Now the problem is there are different route table for different subnet. I want to attach all the private subnet to a single private rt and public subnet to public rt.

```html
module "vpc" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version         = "2.77.0"
  name            = "${var.vpc_name}"
  cidr            = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  azs             = "${var.azs}"
  private_subnets = "${var.private_subnets}"
  public_subnets  = "${var.public_subnets}"

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  enable_nat_gateway = false
  #  single_nat_gateway = true
  create_igw = false

  vpc_tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    Name = "${var.public_subnet_dmz_tag}"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  private_route_table_tags = {
    Name        = "${var.private_route_table_tags}"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  public_route_table_tags = {
    Name        = "${var.public_route_table_tags}"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Without IGW, there are no public subnets. So why not define all private subnets and remove `public_subnets` attribute?

Comment: It is reserved for future reference, client may add igw in the future. Right now I just want the private subnet route tables to be in one single route table with the terraform official vpc module.

Comment: I don't think is possible. I think you would have to fork the entire module and modify its source code to suit your needs.